# Select twins from a list of triples

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

```
list =
  {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 1}, {2, 3, 2}, {4, 5, 6}};
```

To select sublists containing two equal elements ("twins") I wrote:

```
Extract[Position[Length @* Counts /@ list, 2]] @ list
```

{{1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 1}, {2, 3, 2}}

Surprisingly, this was less difficult for me than finding a pattern-based solution:

```
DeleteCases[list, ({x_, y_, z_} /; UnsameQ[x, y, z]) | ({x_, y_, z_} /; SameQ[x, y, z])]
```

{{1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 1}, {2, 3, 2}}

I feel this is much too clumsy for such a mundane task. Is there a shorter, more elegant way to formulate a "twin pattern"?

**Addendum**

The solution should be **pattern-based**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following work for arbitrary list of lists:

```
Cases[{OrderlessPatternSequence[Except[a_] ..., a_, a_]}] @ list

Cases[_?(Not @* FreeQ[2] @* Counts)] @ list

Cases[_?(ContainsAny[{2}] @* Counts)] @ list


Select[Not @* FreeQ[2] @* Counts] @ list

Select[ContainsAny[{2}] @* Counts] @ list
```

All give

> ```
> {{1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 1}, {2, 3, 2}}
> ```

The methods above identify lists that contain *twins* in an arbitrary list of lists. For example,

```
list2 = {{1}, {2, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 5, 2, 3, 5},   
  {1, 5, 2, 3, 2, 5}, {1, 5, 2, 3, 5, 5}};

Cases[{OrderlessPatternSequence[Except[a_] ..., a_, a_]}] @ list2
```

> ```
> {{2, 2}, {1, 5, 2, 3, 5}, {1, 5, 2, 3, 2, 5}}
> ```

For cases where input list is a list of triples, you can also use:

```
Cases[_?(ComapApply @ Nor[UnsameQ, SameQ])] @ list

Select[ComapApply @ Nor[UnsameQ, SameQ]] @ list

DeleteCases[_?(ComapApply @ Or[UnsameQ, SameQ])] @ list
```

Comment: Very good, because I was looking for something like your `OrderlessPatternSequence ` - solution

Answer (score 7):

```
Clear["Global`*"];

list = {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 1}, {2, 3, 
    2}, {4, 5, 6}};

list // DeleteCases[_?(UnsameQ @@ # || SameQ @@ # &)]
```

> {{1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 1}, {2, 3, 2}}

Answer (score 5):

```
Pick[list,Replace[(Sort/@list),{{x_,x_,x_}->False,{x_,x_,_}->True,_List->False},2]]

(* {{1,1,2},{1,2,1},{2,1,1},{2,3,2}} *)
```

**Not Pattern Matching**

```
Pick[list,CountDistinct/@list,2]

(*{{1,1,2},{1,2,1},{2,1,1},{2,3,2}} *)
```

Comment: +1 for the very nice `CountDistinct`

Answer (score 4):

You could try

```
Select[list, EqualTo[2]@*Length@*Tally]
```

Or

```
Select[list, Not@*FreeQ[{_, 2}]@*Tally]
```

Comment: Sorry, lericr, I should have made it clearer, that I am looking for a pattern-based solution. +1 anyway, because your `Select` is better than my `Extract`.

Answer (score 3):

Grabbing the @kglr's pattern and using `SequenceCases`:

```
patt = {OrderlessPatternSequence[Except[a_] .., a_, a_]};

SequenceCases[list, {s : patt} :> s]

(*{{1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 1}, {2, 3, 2}}*)
```

Or using `ReplaceList`:

```
Union@ReplaceList[list, {___, s : patt, ___} :> s]

(*{{1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 1}, {2, 3, 2}}*)
```

Or using `ReplaceAll`:

```
list /. v_?VectorQ /; Equal @@ Unequal @@@ Partition[v, 2, 1, 1] :> Nothing

(*{{1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 1}, {2, 3, 2}}*)
```

Another variant for the pattern and using `ReplaceList`:

```
ReplaceList[list, {__, s : {p___, a_, a_, q__} | {p___, a_, q___, a_}, __} :> s]

(*{{1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 1}, {2, 3, 2}}*)
```

Answer (score 3):

A dirty one:

````
list =
  {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 1}, {2, 3, 2}, {4, 5, 6}};

Cases[list, ({x_, x_, y_} | {y_, x_, x_} | {x_, y_, x_}) /; x != y]

(* {{1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 1}, {2, 3, 2}} *)
```
````

Comment: (+1) Or: `Cases[list, s : Alternatives @@ Permutations[{x_, x_, y_}] /; x != y :> s]`

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps:

```
Fold[Cases[#1, #2] &, {list, {___, a_, ___, a_, ___}, Except[{a_, a_, a_}]}]
```

Comment: (+1) Very nice! :-)

Comment: (+1) you can replace `Cases[#1, #2] &` with `Cases`